# Using Offline JS Library and manifest

Tags: javascript, caching, offline

Is it possible to use [Offline Javascript Library](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) and make the listeners to fire when offline?

The listeners work good when i turn on or off the internet, but when i configure my manifest file (to cache pages) and i declare the library and all pages, it doesnt fire the listeners from this library.

I have this parameters:

```
Offline.options = {
    reconnect: {
        initialDelay: 2 //seconds
    }
}
```

and this listeners:

```
Offline.on('down', function(){
     alert('offline');
});

Offline.on('up', function(){
     alert('online');
});
```

I would like to have all the pages on my manifest file, and still make those listeners to work. Any ideas?

Comment: So you are explicitly caching offline.js in your manifiest but it doesn't work as expected when actually offline? Do you have an example that can be viewed?

Comment: i did the test with one simple html page that includes offlien library and alerts when the user is on or offline and it works well when not using at all manifest. When i add the library and the page to manifest, it doesnt fire the events anymore.

Comment: can you make the test a fiddle? other thing to try might be to set in the options `checkOnLoad: true,` as by default this is false, wait just realised that you more than likely can not put manifest in the fiddle

Comment: i dont know how to add manifest file on jsfiddle. But basically i just have the options and then the listeners, and thats all. I tried with **checkOnLoad** option but still doesnt fire anything.

Comment: Well this way madness lies - so i tried this out on my own website to see what was happening and it correctly tells me when i go offline but when i reconnect it never actual goes back online. just keeps thinking it is offline.and then if i start offline it says i am online but when i do reconnect my wifi it says online!! MADNESS!! is this the same thing you are seeing, here is my test site to see the results i was on about http://quincewebdesign.com/test-offline/. This may be a chrome thing mixed with the cache manifest but going to investigate furter

Comment: Yes, i had the same problem! I am still trying to figure out whats going on.